# How to return two Python objects to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, python-2.7, return-value

I have this HTML and JS code where I send by POST the following form, where at first it evaluated if in the HTML those elements were selected.

page.HTML

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 70%;">
     <ul>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="biblioteca[]" value="biblioteca" id="rd-biblioteca"/>
           <p class="label-text">Biblioteca </p>
         </li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="revistas" id="cb-revistas"/>
            <p class="label-text">Revistas </p>
         </li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="novelas" id="cb-novelas"/>
            <p class="label-text">Novelas </p>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

file.js

```
$('#msform').validate({
       submitHandler: function (form) {
           $('#rd-biblioteca').is(':checked')?$('#rd-biblioteca').val():$('#rd-biblioteca').val(0);
           $('#cb-revistas').is(':checked')?$('#cb-revistas').val():$('#cb-revistas').val(0);
           $('#cb-novelas').is(':checked')?$('#cb-novelas').val():$('#cb-novelas').val(0);
           form.submit();
       }
   });
```

In the views.py I get the POST and then ask if the values ​​are the ones that were selected and if so, an object called Info is created and saved in ListaProject.

views.py

```
def school(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        listaProject = []

        if request.POST.get("biblioteca[]") == 'biblioteca':

            if request.POST.get("books[]") == 'revistas':
                revistas = Info(titulo="Titulo ..",
                                descripcion="Descripcion ...",
                                precio="Precio ...")
                listaProject.append(cocina)
            else:
                if request.POST.get("books[]") == 'novelas':
                    novelas = Info(titulo="Titulo 2...",
                                  descripcion="Descripcion 2...",
                                  precio="Precio 2...")
                    listaProject.append(nube)
        return render_to_response("v2/index.html", {'listaProject': listaProject},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        response_data = {}
        response_data['response'] = "ok"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

What I need to know is how to make selecting the two checkboxes for books [] show the two objects, since only one is displayed, even though you select both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get  multiple selected checkbox value ,by changing in js and view file.Hope it helps you

```
$('#msform').validate({
   submitHandler: function (form) {
       allVals=[]

       $('#rd-biblioteca').is(':checked')?$('#rd-biblioteca').val():$('#rd-biblioteca').val(0);

      $('input[name="books[]"]:checked').each(function () {
          allVals.push($(this).val());
        });/*you can get multiple selected checkbox list in array */
       form.submit();
   } });
```

Change in View file:

```
def school(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    listaProject = []


        if request.POST.get("biblioteca[]") == 'biblioteca':
            revistas = Info(titulo="Titulo ..",
                            descripcion="Descripcion ...",
                            precio="Precio ...")
            listaProject.append(cocina)
        else:
            if request.POST.get("books[]") == 'revistas' or 'novelas':
                novelas = Info(titulo="Titulo 2...",
                              descripcion="Descripcion 2...",
                              precio="Precio 2...")
                listaProject.append(nube)
    return render_to_response("v2/index.html", {'listaProject': listaProject},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    response_data = {}
    response_data['response'] = "ok"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")`enter code here`
```